# Правопис прізвищ іншомовного походження

Tags: власні-назви, орфографія, spelling, іноземні-імена

В цікавій статті [13 кривавих трагедій давнього Львова, скоєних на любовному ґрунті](http://photo-lviv.in.ua/13-kryvavyh-trahedij-davnoho-lvova-skojenyh-na-lyubovnomu-grunti/) надаються приклади статей з Львовських газет 1936 року. В одній з заміток згадуються декілька прізвищ, які пишуться за старими правилами.

> За дівчину
>
> Влад. **Войтиньскі** повідомив поліцію, що на вул. Старознесінській напали
>   на нього два замасковані осібняки й побили його дрючком по голові.
>   Войтиньскі підозріває, що на нього напали Юзеф **Пясецкі** й Мирослав
>   **Шинаровский**. Вони обидва лихі на нього за те, що він ходить з Аделею
>   Сенценівною, в якій любиться Пясецкі.

Два прізвища польського походження (Войтиньскі і Пясецкі) і пишуться так, як в польській мові (з закінченням на `і`), а от походження третього прізвища (Шинаровский) мені не зовсім зрозуміле.

Якщо прізвище **Шинаровский** українського походження, то чому воно без `ь` знака?

Чи може воно російського походження і раніше існувало правило напису іншомовних імен так, як вони вимовляються в іншій мові?

Сучасний [Український правопис](http://litopys.org.ua/pravopys/rozdil4.htm) пропонує

> § 104. Фонетичні правила правопису слов’янських прізвищ
>   **-СК(ИЙ), -ЦК(ИЙ)** та ін.
>
> 9. Суфікси слов’янських прізвищ **-ск(ий)**, **-цк(ий)**, **-ск(і)**, **-цк(і)**, **-sk(i)**, **-ck(i)**, **-dzk(i)**, **-sk(ý)**, **-ck(ý)** передаються відповідно через **-ськ(ий)**, **-цьк(ий)**, **-дзьк(ий)**: *Броневський, Даргомижський, Маяковський, Мусоргський, Островський; Гомулицький, Городецький; Грудзький, Завадзький; так само
>      з ь пишуться російські прізвища на -ск(ой), -цк(ой): Луговськой
>      (Луговська), Трубецькой (Трубецька)*.

Але й досі можна зустріти коли прізвища польского походження пишуть за старими правилами (`-скі`, а не `-ський`). Наприклад, новини ТСН про розслідування катастрофи з Лехом Качиньскі [#качиньскі](https://tsn.ua/tags/%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%8C%D1%81%D0%BA%D1%96). В той же час Вікіпедія подає статтю про [Леха Качиньського](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9B%D0%B5%D1%85_%D0%9A%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9) за сучасним правописом.

Отже цікаво, чи це правило українського правопису відносно нове (2015 року?) і раніше все ж дозволялося вживати `-скі`, чи існують/існувало декілька паралельних правописів, чи це просто безграмотність наших журналістів?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

За правописом УСРР 1926 року, який можна подивитися [тут](https://ukrainian.meta.stackexchange.com/a/119/69), польські прізвища  Войтиньскі та Пясецкі повинні були б бути записані із закінченням -ий (в кінці картинки є Cegielski = Цегельський):

[image: польські прізвища]

Але в ті роки (1936) Львів був у складі Польщі, тому на Польщу всі ці правописи навряд чи розповсюджувалися.

*Щоправда краще користуватися "скрипниківкою" - Харківським правописом 1929 року що мав офіційний статус, але для Польщі він все одно не був аргументом.*

---

Щодо Польщі, точніше Львова, є "Правописні правила Наукового Товариства Шевченка" (1922), вони також пропонують у кінці польських прізвищ писати -ий:
[image: Наукове товариство Шевченка]

Ці правила базувалися на "Найголовніших правилах українського правопису", виданих у 1921 р. у Києві.

Хоча, можливо у газеті користувалися Желехівкою (що була [затверджена урядом Австро-Угорщини](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%96%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D1%85%D1%96%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0#.D0.9A.D1.80.D0.B8.D1.82.D0.B8.D0.BA.D0.B0)), або "Руска граматика" (1893), яка використовувалася [у якості підручника](http://litopys.org.ua/ohukr/ohu20.htm). У цих правописах був закладений фонетичний принцип,
хоча ось що пише "Руска граматика":

[image: Ruska Gramatyka]

Для тих імен що "Меньше знані" пропонується писати їх мовою оригіналу:

[image: мовою оригіналу]

Картинки з "Історії українського правопису" ([djvu-файл](http://lib.movahistory.org.ua/PRAWOPYS/Nimchuk_Istoriya_ukr_pravopysu_2004_OCR+Zmist.djvu)).

---

Щодо того чи були журналісти безграмотними - важко сказати лише на основі правописів, тим більше що "Руска граматика" пишуть що додавати "-ий" треба в тому разі, коли ці прізвища "приняли руський вид, або цілком зрущили ся".

Отже, або Войтинські та Пясецькі "не приняли руський вид", або у польському мовному середовищі (а особливо у кримінальній хроніці) заміна "-кі" на "-кий" по-перше не співпадає з мовною практикою, а по-друге може привести до плутанини: Войтинські - польське прізвище, Войтинський - вже українське, можливо обидва прізвища могли співіснувати одночасно.

Comment: Справа в тому, що в польській мові  після _k_ не може бути _y_ (наше И), лише _і_, тому всі польські прізвища в питанні в польскій орфографії закінчуються на _-ki_ (напр. _Kaczyński_). А в цьому витягу з правопису 1926 йдеться лише про польські прізвища на _-у_. І там незрозуміло про м’які прикметники, що, треба було писати _Качинськ**і**й_?

Comment: Там в кінці картинки є Cegielski = Цегельський. Про закінчення -і не сказано, але у прикладах воно зустрічається.

Comment: Дякую за відповідь. Тобто ті журналісти, що пишуть _Качинські_, не вчили правила в школі і просто зробили транслітерацію польського прізвища?

Comment: @Ivan Можливо вони все-ж таки користувалися фонетичним принципом. Бо інакше не зрозуміло чого російські дипломати протестували: "Ця перемога фонетики над етимологією в Галичині та Буковині, по семилітній впертій боротьбі, сталася головно тому, що за неї стояли й урядові чинники, бо їх Смаль-Стоцький та Ґартнер переконали в великій користі правописної реформи;<...>. Справа доходила навіть до того, що російський уряд дипломатичною дорогою протестував проти зміни етимологічного письма на фонетичне."