# Ейнштейн чи Айнштайн?

Tags: власні-назви, правопис, запозичені-слова, орфографія, іноземні-імена

Більш звично (шкільна програма фізики) та більш вживаним є варіант ***Альберт Ейнштейн***, але нещодавно побачила в підручнику [Астрономія 11 клас](http://pidruchnyk.com.ua/442-astronomya-prishlyak-11-klas.html) ***Альберт Айнштайн***. Як доказ правильності Айнштайн є те, що не правильно зробили переклад з німецької, зокрема це зазначено на сторінці [Альберт Ейнштейн (також Айнштайн)](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B1%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%82_%D0%95%D0%B9%D0%BD%D1%88%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%B9%D0%BD). Який з цих варіантів є доречнішим при написані наукової роботи?

Comment: Related: https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/q/868/ і https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/q/3070/ Взагалі, у нас є кілька запитань на цю тему, і було б цікаво якось їх обʼєднати… бо інакше ризикуємо тим, що постійно подібні запитання зʼявлятимуться, і їх буде важко закривати, бо вони ж не будуть exact duplicate.

Comment: @bytebuster можна щонайменше об’єднати просто транслітерацію німецького "еі". Бо там і Гайне, і Фоґельвайде, і Ляйбніц, і Вайсе. Було б ще гарно призвати дух palascinta, бо вона в цих справах найспритніше все пояснювала і найдокладніше, а я злий.

Comment: @bytebuster але взагалі я б почекав з відповіддю, поки не вийде новий правопис, бо у сьогоднішній навіть зазирати не хочу, бо там як завжди буде щось типу "завжди передається як "ай", окрім деяких випадків (які абсолютно нереґламентовані жодним чином). Або навпаки взагалі "завжди як "ей", але іноді як "ай". Коротше, можна зробити загальнішу відповідь під вихід нового правопису і сподіватися, що вони не прогнуться знову під більшість, а запустять круті зміни.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

#### Ориґінал

Німецькою це прізвище пишеться [так](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Albert_Einstein):

> Einstein

#### Правопис

Сучасний правопис української мови 2019 року [каже](https://mon.gov.ua/storage/app/media/zagalna%20serednya/05062019-onovl-pravo.pdf):

> Німецьке буквосполучення **еі** відповідно до вимови передаємо українською мовою через **ай (яй)**: Айзена́х, Ва́йнрайх, Віттгеншта́йн, Ва́йзенборн, Ка́йзер, Ма́йнгоф, Нортга́йм, Бляйбтрой, Кляйн, Кляйнерт, Фляйшер.

#### Висновок

## "Einstein" українською треба передавати як "Айнштайн".

#### Можливе заперечення висновку

Можна заперечити іншою цитатою з правопису:

> За традицією в давніших запозиченнях німецьке буквосполучення еі передаємо в транслітерованому вигляді через ей: кре́йда, кре́йцер, маркше́йдер, капельме́йстер, гросме́йстер, штрейкбре́хер, Ге́йне, Ле́йпциг, Рейн, Швейца́рія.

#### Спростування заперечення

Але таке заперечення швидко спростовується:

У першому списку бачимо "Віттгенштайн". [Роки життя Віттгенштайна](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9B%D1%8E%D0%B4%D0%B2%D1%96%D0%B3_%D0%92%D1%96%D1%82%D0%B3%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%88%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BD) - 1889-1951. [Роки життя Айнштайна](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Albert_Einstein) - 1879-1955. Немає сенсу долучати Айнштайна до давніших запозичень. Пишемо через "а".

До того ж, формулювання "за традицією" дуже непевне, тому найкраще просто обмежитися тими словами, що прямо вказані у списку після двокрапки, а все решту писати за основним правилом.

Answer (score -3):

Все почалося, коли в 2015 році українські мовознавці взялися за розробку нового українського правопису, [де](http://www.yatran.com.ua/articles/703.html) йшлося:

> Багато уточнень потребує написання загальних іменників та власних назв
>   іншомовного походження. Бо в радянський період усі ці назви в нас
>   упроваджували через посередництво російської мови. Українська мова
>   була позбавлена самостійності. Тому ми кажемо, наприклад, Брейгель
>   (прізвище живописця), бо так у Росії. Але, наприклад, у Німеччині
>   ніхто не зрозуміє, кого маємо на увазі. Там прізвище звучить як
>   Бройгель. Водночас прізвище знаного фізика Ейнштейна там вимовляють
>   Айнштайн. Так би мали писати та говорити і ми. Тобто бажано
>   використовувати форму вимови тієї мови, з якої слово запозичене.

Зараз цей пункт мав би бути включеним до [Проекту правопису 2018](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%83_2018_%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%83), однак на самій Вікіпедії, я потрібного пункту не знайшов, але там ж і пише "деякі пункти", такщо, можливо, зовсім скоро згідно до нового правопису писатиметься лише "Айнштайн", а не "Ейнштейн" (з чим я погоджуюся, бо ж в німецькій мові це прізвище саме так і вимовляється).

Comment: Ви впевнені, що все почалося у 2015, а не у 1928 або 1933 роках, наприклад?

Comment: Я пишу про те, що в 2015 році почалися нові зміни правопису, і, що саме  раніше в шкільних підручниках писали "Ейнштейн", а зараз через це починають (не впенений, бо сам такого не бачив, але суджу з самого запитання та з вкладень у ньому) писати "Айнштайн". Про правопис 1933 року і його вплив я знаю, бо вже давав відповідь на це запитання на цьому ж сайті.

Comment: якщо подивитися в підручник, який вказаний в запитанні, то видно що він виданий в 2011 році. Тому Ваша відповідь "що все пчалося в 2015 році", не зовсім коректна

Comment: Я згоден з P. Vovk і Mariia Matskevych, що ці хитання не пов'язані з проектом-2018 (написання якого почалось у 2015), а йдуть від невідповідності нашої традиційної адаптації цього імені (Ейнштейн) оригінальній вимові (нім. [ˈaɪnʃtaɪn], англ. /ˈaɪnstaɪn/). Тому періодично з'являються «реформатори» («навіщо нам ця (можливо, від росіян) традиція, давайте писати як в оригіналі») і «консерватори» («та ви що, завжди ж писали по-старому, й продовжувати по-старому будемо»). Проект-2018 лише може підтримати «реформаторів» (дозволивши новий варіант або обидва) — але не певен, що робить це.

Comment: Та стаття, що Ви знайшли, каже, що проект-2018 _мав би_ розв'язати це питання. Але _запит_ на це питання з'явився очевидно раніше 2015.

Comment: В книжці взагалі пише Айштайн (ст. 153)... Так от, ось правопис 2012го року - http://izbornyk.org.ua/pravopys/pravopys2012.htm, ось виноска з нього - https://maksymus.livejournal.com/106055.html, там пише, що Ейнштейн, тобто у всіх книгах,тим більше для навчальних закладів мало б бути так і я не звернув увагу, що книжка 11го року. Можливо, це справді був якийсь "реформаторський" хід від авторів, але факт залишається фактом - до 2015 року в більшості книжок і згідно до офіційного правопису писали Ейнштейн, а зараз відбуваються знову зміни.

Comment: Так, це «реформаторський» хід авторів підручника. І навіть не лише до 2015, а до поточного моменту включно згідно з чинним правописом мають надавати перевагу написанню _Ейнштейн_ — бо новий проект ще не ухвалено. Й не факт, що його взагалі буде ухвалено (тобто зміни зараз лише _пропонуються_, але чи _ухвалять_ їх — невідомо).

Answer (score -3):

> Тому ми кажемо, наприклад, Брейгель (прізвище живописця), бо так у Росії. Але, наприклад, у Німеччині ніхто не зрозуміє, кого маємо на увазі. Там прізвище звучить як Бройгель

До чого тут Німеччина? Брейгель - голландець. І вимовляють це слово там так https://ru.forvo.com/search/Bruegel/ .

P.S. Це не моя суб'єктивна думка. Це факт, який маємо сприймати "as is".

P.P.S. До речі, "Євген" там (у Німеччині) вимовляють як "Ойґен", а "євро" - як "ойро", "Європа" ("Европа") - "Ойропа". Ми маємо на це якось реагувати, у контексті мовної реформи?
Є певні межі розумного, за які виходити не можна, за якими реформа перетворюється на експеримент над суспільством.

Comment: Дозволена лише Українська і Анґлійська, до того ж, коли запитанє Українською, то відповідь Анґлійською мусе мати також поруч Українського перекладу. Инші мови дозволені хіба шчо як витяг, котра теж мусе мати перекладу і ясностї. Також зазначу, же відповідь, як я зрозумів, «там вимовяють так» — не дуже ладна, варто зазначити також вимову хоча б за допомогою [МФА](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/Міжнародний_фонетичний_алфавіт) і внести свої ясностї.

Comment: Шчо ж, шчиро дякую за виправу мови. Тепер залишило ся навести МФА чи штиб цього, а також навести ясні і тверезі арґументи, а не переводити стрілки, наприклад слова Евген і Евро — грецького ходу. Кажете про неокреслені межи. Арґументовано напишіть, як правильно вимовяти за вашою думкою і чому.

Comment: > Дозволена лише Українська і Анґлійська > Инші мови дозволені хіба шчо як витяг, котра теж мусе мати перекладу і ясностї. Наперед перепрошую. Ваша мова (якою Ви пишете) також не є унормованою літературною українською. Безумовно, я Вас зрозумів, як і Ви мене (російською). Але нормативними наразі є "інші", "що", "виняток". "Витяг" є певно якимось діалектизмом. Та й "мусе мати" - не дуже, як на мене. > відповідь, як я зрозумів, «там вимовяють так» — не дуже ладна Моя відповідь доповнена посиланням, за яким наведені аудіо зі зразками вимови носіїв згадуваної (голландської) мови. > а не переводити

Comment: для прочитання повної відповіді на попередні два коментарі - перейдіть до цього посту: https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/a/5986/240